# What does 'hush your mouth' mean when Elton John says it?

Tags: lyrics

In Elton John's song 'Porch Swing in Tupelo' when the following lyric is sung.

> There's a porch swing in Tupelo
>   In the shade of the south
>   Where the sweet honey drips off that   > old hush-yo'-mouth

I know that 'hush your mouth' means 'be quiet' but I'm not sure in this context.

Comment: It could be that it is being used in place of (to cover up or censor) the real, but inappropriate, word in that line of thought.

Comment: Elton John is singing about the porch swing in the house in Tupelo, Mississippi, where Elvis Presley was born, and which is now a museum site. The 'sweet honey' may refer to the specialist 'Tupelo' honey, from Tupelo trees, but I think it's more likely to be imagery for the vocal sounds or sweet music emanating from the mouth (hush yo' mouth) of Elvis, seated on the porch swing.

Comment: "Shut yo mouth" is not the same as *hush your mouth*, the former is American English, meaning "don't talk any more", it could also be a variation of "shut up" which is said used to expresses "disbelief" and "amazement".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Shut-yo-mouth](http://drickscafe.com/shut-yo-mouth-recipes-meat-pies/)*** refers to a recipe:

> - I bet in all regions, heck, all parts of this world, you fine folks have a slew of food dishes you just love to make … you know the ones that are so gosh darn good, but because of the name or maybe ingredients, you just don’t go around praising the worthiness. Well, that is what Shut Yo Mouth is all about.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've loved the song for so long and only just now had it clarified. Thanks again.

Comment: *Hush yo mouth* is not the same as [*shut yo' mouth*](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/shut-yo'-mouth), and the recipe described is called Cooter pie, which is slang for turtles. The whole article seems like a spoof, or extremely informal.